# How to update a single element in an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript

In the example below, what is the correct way to change `null` to `'Hugo'`?

```javascript
const airplaneSeats = [
  ['Ruth', 'Anthony', 'Stevie'],
  ['Amelia', 'Pedro', 'Maya'],
  ['Xavier', 'Ananya', 'Luis'],
  ['Luke', null, 'Deniz'],
  ['Rin', 'Sakura', 'Francisco']
]
```

I tried doing `airplaneSeats.splice([3][1], 1, 'Hugo')` but this was wrong. Why?
Also, I was told that the answer was  `airplaneSeats[3][1] = 'Hugo'`, which didn't make sense because how does that delete `null`?

Comment: Array indexes are 0 based,   0,1,2,3  4th array down,  0,1,  2nd array right,  And now your just replacing what's at that index.   IOW: it doesn't delete, it replaces..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: _also i got back that the answer was `airplaneSeats[3][1] = 'Hugo'` which didn't make sense because how does that delete null_ Trying to not sound snarky... Have you looked at any basic JS introductions/tutorials? Variables and assignment should be one of the first things covered, and array element access (which is dynamic object property access) should be covered right near the beginning of any properly introductory introduction to arrays.

Comment: Why does ... _"`airplaneSeats[3][1] = 'Hugo'` ...[not] make sense"_? **It does exactly what the OP did ask for** ... _"update[ing] a single element in an array of arrays"_. Thus `null` gets replaced by `'Hugo'`. The OP might `console.log` the `airplaneSeats` array before and after the re/assignment.

Comment: Keith, when you mean 0 based  you mean it Strat at 0 right? null is on the 3rd line 
we learn splice earlier so I think i got them mix up, I thought I needed to delete and input hugo

Comment: Darryl Noakes, the lesson was on Multi-Dimensional Arrays. he showed us using a tic tac toe game in the console. I may have but i forget sometime, so after finishings JS i will redo everything

Comment: Your question is probably being downvoted by persons who think it is too basic and that you should have found a tutorial instead of asking a question here. But updating the title and adding a message at the start of the body is not the way to resolve that. Rather just post a comment, and _maybe_ add a section at the end asking what can be improved. If you think that's not enough, you can ask a question on [meta].

Comment: I did not downvote it; I have instead tried to help improve it. My suggestions were based on site standards, policies, and best practices.

Comment: One of the "before you answer" recommendations is at least preliminary googling, reading docs, etc. See the [FAQ on research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/15261914).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `splice` function to replace an item in a nested array, you need to use something like my code below.

```
airplaneSeats[3].splice(1, 1, 'Hugo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Hugo to that location by setting the graph coordinate like so:

```
airplaneSeats[3][1] = 'Hugo';
```

As for what you tried - you can't use chained index accessing meant for graph index access `[i][j]` as a parameter for the Array prototype method splice. You must iterate over the 1st array and use splice on the sub Array using a single index as a parameter.

The function `fillNull` below will iterate over the `graph` and then use common Array methods to check for `null` and fill all instances of `null` with `val`.

```
const airplaneSeats = [
  ['Ruth', 'Anthony', 'Stevie'],
  ['Amelia', 'Pedro', 'Maya'],
  ['Xavier', 'Ananya', 'Luis'],
  ['Luke', null, 'Deniz'],
  ['Rin', 'Sakura', 'Francisco']
] 

const fillNull = (graph, val) => {
    graph.forEach((line) => {
        let i = line.indexOf(null);
        i > -1 && line.splice(i, 1, val);
    })
    return graph;
}

fillNull(airplaneSeats, 'Hugo');
```

However, if you want a more reusable function I would break out of the check after Hugo is added to the first seat.

```
// two empty seats
const airplaneSeats = [
  ['Ruth', 'Anthony', 'Stevie'],
  ['Amelia', null, 'Maya'],  // <-- Hugo will sit here
  ['Xavier', 'Ananya', 'Luis'],
  ['Luke', null, 'Deniz'],
  ['Rin', 'Sakura', 'Francisco']
] 

const fillNull = (graph, val) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
        let seat = graph[i].indexOf(null);
        if (seat > -1) {
            graph[i].splice(seat, 1, val);
            break; // Hugo sits down in first null 
        }
    }
    return graph;
}

fillNull(airplaneSeats, 'Hugo');
```